# How to temporarily set java path in a slurm batchfile?

Tags: java, environment-variables, java-home, slurm

Good morning,

at the moment I'm trying to test several frameworks on a cluster administered by SLURM. One problem that comes up again and again is, that the cluster uses java 7 at JAVA_HOME (and getting it updated is ... no option). Our (layered) jobs do use java 8 for the most part.

Now it's simple enough to start a job using a different java version. BUT: some of the dependencies of third party frameworks are adamant in using the JAVA_HOME version, and often do not come with configs to change that.

My guesstimate is that it's possible via the export environment variable functionality, but I can't find documentation to help me further along this path.

Summary:

Is there a way to overrule the JAVA-HOME global setting for a full slurm job? If yes, how to do so, or were to find documentation on that feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a standard Linux feature that a new process copies all exported environment variables from its parent process when it is started. So setting JAVA_HOME once at the appropriate place should be enough unless it gets reset somewhere down the chain.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried: export JAVA_HOME=<java_path_here> but somehow it doesn't take. Other environmental variables work just fine (I'm using them routinely). Im not sure if that's slurm specific or whatever.

Comment: Do you have java in the PATH as well? Maybe this is where the wrong version comes from.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, I had to prepend the path instead of append it.